# How to Get Closest Location in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to get the closest location via my LINQ query:

```
var coord = new GeoCoordinate(loc.Latitude, loc.Longitude);
var nearest = ctx.Locations
                 .Select(x => new LocationResult {
                     location = x,
                     coord = new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude.GetValueOrDefault(),
                                               x.Longitude.GetValueOrDefault())
                 })
                 .OrderBy(x => x.coord.GetDistanceTo(coord))
                 .First();

return nearest.location.Id;
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

I have tried Googling this but I am still not sure how to fix it.  What is a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Is it possible to write it as: new GeoCoordinate{x.Latitude.GetValueOrDefault(), x.Longitude.GetValueOrDefault()}

Comment: @jyparask - huh? that's not even going to build.

Comment: Can you share LocationResult class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try this instead:

```
var coord = new GeoCoordinate(loc.Latitude, loc.Longitude);
                var nearest = ctx.Locations
                    .Select(x => new LocationResult {
                        location = x,
                        coord = new GeoCoordinate { Latitude = x.Latitude ?? 0, Longitude = x.Longitude ?? 0 }
                    })
                    .OrderBy(x => x.coord.GetDistanceTo(coord))
                    .First();

                return nearest.location.Id;
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get the following error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double GetValueOrDefault()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: @user1477388 try `x.Latitude ?? 0`. Linq to Entities recognize the null-coalescing operator.

Comment: @SimonBelanger That may work, so thanks; but I just tried adding `.AsEnumerable()` before my `.Select()` and it works.

Comment: @user1477388 It will but you will get the whole table. `AsEnumerable` exits the Entity Framework's `IQueryProvider` world. Since you are using a `First`, I'd strongly suggest not using `AsEnumerable` to avoid fetching more records than required.

Comment: @SimonBelanger I have tried using `Latitude = x.Latitude ?? 0` and also for `Longitude` but it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line

```
new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude.GetValueOrDefault(), x.Longitude.GetValueOrDefault())
```

This is using a constructor with a parameter becuase the GeoCoordiante class's constructor is called with a couple of parameters.

A paramaterless constructor is a constructor for a type that does not take any parameters.

Comment: Right, this is completely useless.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, though.